# When I flip my sprite it goes out of the tilemaps foreground

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I came across a problem that I can't solve. Whenever I move my character if it's near the edge of the map it goes through the tilemaps collider and goes out of the map. Here's the screenshot I took:

This is normal: [link text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14_NQ_0VOcgtpOGPyssp5wkJ-VwH4f5cB/view)

This is when the bug occurs: [bug](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p-ezmUsVwmqyb3oT4kozP-iEQaMOSi9D/view?usp=sharing)

Here's the code I'm using to move and flip the character:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
 
 public class MovementScript : MonoBehaviour
 {
     Vector2 moveInput;
 
     Animator animator;
     Rigidbody2D rb;
     BoxCollider2D myCollider;
     PlayerStats playerStats;
     float playerSpeed;
    
     [SerializeField] float timeToWaitAfterBeingAttackedToMoveAgain = 1f;
     [SerializeField] int kickbackFromEnemyAttack = 40;
 
     void Start()
     {
         myCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
         rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
         animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
         playerStats = GetComponent<PlayerStats>();
     }
 
     void FixedUpdate()
     {
         playerSpeed = playerStats.GetPlayerSpeed();
         if(playerStats.PlayerIsAlive())
         {
             Run();
             FlipSprite();
         }        
     }
 
     //If the player goes left the sprite flips left, otherwise it flips to the right
     void FlipSprite()
     {
         bool playerHasHorizontalSpeed = Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.x) >= Mathf.Epsilon;
 
         if(playerHasHorizontalSpeed)
         {
             transform.localScale = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(rb.velocity.x), 1f);
         }
     }
 
     void Run()
     {        
         Vector2 playerVelocity = new(moveInput.x * playerSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
         rb.velocity = playerVelocity;
         
         if (myCollider.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Ground")))
         {
             animator.SetBool("run", Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.x) >= Mathf.Epsilon);
         }   
     }
 
     void OnMove(InputValue value)
     {
         moveInput = value.Get<Vector2>();
     }     
 
     private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
     {
         if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy") && playerStats.PlayerIsAlive())
         {            
             this.enabled = false;
             TriggerKickup();
             StartCoroutine(ActivateMovement());
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’d likely be better to get the SpriteRenderer component and change its flipX property rather than reversing the scale.

Either way, if the sprite is moving in an unintended way when you flip it, it’s likely that the pivot isn’t set the way you want it — e.g. in this case it’s probably set to the bottom left of the sprite.

Select the sprite asset, click “Sprite Editor” in the inspector, and set the sprite’s pivot to the middle or bottom middle. Apply the changes and the sprite should flip from the centre instead of from the edge.

Comment: Note that you will need to position sprites in the middle rather than the left of the tiles if you change the pivot. If you *really* didn't want to have to change that, you could instead apply an offset when flipping sprites, but that offset would be dependent on the width of the sprite, plus if you have any lopsided sprites you'd be back to needing to change the pivot.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your answer and all the details. I changed the pivor and it worked as intended!